# What does that mark indicate in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

[image]

I downloaded the code from GIT and was trying to set up the androids code but I faced this problem ,an annotation on the project and subsequent files .
Plz let me know what does that mark in the project explorer over "Main Activity" (project as well as .java file)indicate.

if image is not visible properly plz download.
and what does that indicate ,any tips to resolve it are most welcome.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: have u installed git plugins into an eclipse?

Comment: no.
but there were other projects I had downloaded earlier,they were all working fine.

Comment: but what do we call that annotation (name of that annotation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the > character, it is just telling you that the .java file (and therefore the project) have been changed compared to the version in GIT.

You can configure these 'Label Decorations' in `Preferences > Team > Git > Label Decorations > Text Decorations tab`.

Comment: greg can u explain a bit
do u mean to configure all the folders ,variable ,and files present in the package

Comment: The configuration lets you say if you want this decoration to be shown or not. You do not have to configure it for individual files.